# Video not playing in webview in android

Tags: android

In my default browser when i am hitting the following link
http://118.102.182.53:9080/swami/index.html
video integrated in this html file is playing perfectly, but when i am trying to load the same url within my app's web view video is not playing .

Can any body help me..or any clue.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Share your source code... did you enable javascript?

Comment: Here is my Code:::::::webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
     
     
  
     
     webView.loadUrl("http://118.102.182.53:9080/swami/index.html");

Comment: Though i have able to solve the issue...stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video, here is discussed the solution...Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to the `WebViewClient`, you should also add a `WebChromeClient` to the `WebView`

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());               
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);              
webView.loadUrl("http://118.102.182.53:9080/swami/index.html");
```

For Android version 3.x you can also set `hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the AndroidManifest.xml.